# Win2012R2 RAID 1 - when reading which mirror drive is read from - both or picks at random or fastest

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, raid

Using Windows 2012R2 Software RAID on AWS EC2 instance

If I have two drives, and SSD and an HDD and I put them in a mirror, I understand that writes will be speed of slowest.
But what about reading?  Is it a random selection?  Does it read both?  Does it somehow measure and pick the slowest or fastest?  Is it the drive with the lowest pending reads?

Any info appreciated.  Reason I am asking is to see if I can mirror instance storage drives

Comment: Did you try testing your system to find out?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: We are in process of doing that.  I want to get the current understanding so that we can put any results in context.  If we see a certain performance we want to understand why, not just assume and find that it changes down the line.

Comment: So prem testing shows it is reading at fasting drive speed  and writing at slowest.  Does this fit with how it works?  How does it know which is fastest?

Answer (score 1):

This configuration is rare and not efficient at all. Anyway, you will get write speed of HDD. As for the reads, maybe it will depend on drive choose priority upon creation of RAID, or from sata slots...

Or it even can differ from reboot to reboot, have you tried to test these options?